# How to move map annotation with animation in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: ios, mapkit, xamarin, key-value-observing

I have custom annotation (`MKAnnotation` inheritor) and I would like to move it after `AddAnnotation`.

`Coordinate` property is overridden but KVO (on which animation of `setCoordinate:` is based) doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by manually calling KVO `willChangeValue` and `didChangeValue` methods in setter of `Coordinate` property. Like this:

```
    public override CLLocationCoordinate2D Coordinate 
    {
        get
        {
            var loc = UserInfo.Activity.MapLocation.Location;
            return new CLLocationCoordinate2D(loc.Latitude, loc.Longitude);
        }

        set
        {
            WillChangeValue("coordinate");

            //Save value here to some backing store
            //e.g. _coordinate = value

            DidChangeValue("coordinate");
        }
    }
```

Animate it like that:

```
UIView.AnimateNotify(1.0, () => {
    myAnnotation.Coordinate = targetCoordinates;
}, finished => {

});
```

I also had problem that if add several annotations, one of them is moved from left top corner. I solved it by wrapping animation code above in background thread:

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => {
   InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
       UIView.AnimateNotify(1.0, () => {
           myAnnotation.Coordinate = targetCoordinates;
           secondAnnotation.Coordinate = secondCoordinates;
       }, finished => {

       });
   });
});
```

It's a bit hacky, but it works. It gives method that calls `AddAnnotations` opportunity to return, and then updates coordinates. You could probably do the same with animation delay, but it didn't work for me.